# GraphQL file upload using JavaScript Fetch

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm trying to upload files to a GraphQL server, my code looks like this:

```
        var query = "{ course(id: 1) { title } }"

        const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        const url = "http://server.com:3000/graphql";

        var response = await fetch(proxyurl + url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ query: query }),
        })
        var json = await response.json();
        console.log(json.data.course.title);
```

I'm not sure how to translate a sample CURL request someone made as an example:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:3001/graphql \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'operations={"query":"mutation ($files: [Upload!]!) {multipleUpload(files: $files) {id filename encoding mimetype path __typename}}","variables":{}}' \
  -F 'map={"0":["variables.files.0"],"1":["variables.files.1"]}' \
  -F '"0"=@/Users/giautm/Devel/IMG_0636.JPG' \
  -F '"1"=@/Users/giautm/Devel/IMG_0637.JPG'
```

EDIT:

This is the mutation I'm trying to accomplish:

```
mutation identityValidation{
  validateIdentity(identity:{
    card_back:"", #must be an Upload scalar
    card_front:"", #must be an Upload scalar
    uniqueID:"" #string
  }){
    name,
    status,
    message
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: search 'send multipart/form-data using XXX'

Comment: File uploading functionality is not a part of graphql, however I can tell from the curl request that you want to upload the files using multipart method, it would be easier to implement it using Apollo client and server. Otherwise please encode images as base64 before sending them, then decode on the server if files are expected to be small.

Comment: Can you please confirm if the server is using Apollo or supports multipart file upload already ?

Comment: Yes, the server is using Apollo, I also edited the question, the mutation receives an input parameter with 2 upload scalars and 1 string

Comment: it doesn't matter ... always test API first using f.e. Postman ... then recreate it using fetch/axios/whatever comparing detaily request body with postman's ... start with one file, you'll find many examples/tutorials

Comment: I'm using curl and postman, if anything arises I will come back with more information. Thanks!